# org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Bad contentType for search handler :application/xml; charset=UTF-8

Tags: solr, pysolr

my current solr version is 8.3.* and using pysolr to search in solr.

here is my code

```
solr_new = pysolr.Solr('my solr url')

feeds_new = solr_new.search("id:325387975")
```

search line throws exception

```
Bad contentType for search handler :application/xml; charset=UTF-8 request={q=325387975&wt=json}
```

Comment: can you try by setting the("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
and ("Accept", "application/json") in your http headers

Comment: headers = {
                'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            }

Comment: Thanks, but i have resolved the issue.

Comment: How did you resolved the same?I mean, what changes you did to resolve the same?

Comment: i just update my pysolr package, solr 8.3 version and pysolr==3.0.1 are not compatible, so i just update my pysolr to latest.

Comment: I had the same issue -- without "application/json" gave error --> "application/json;" worked ok -- the semicolon in the end made a difference.